# SQL--> joining tables issue

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

I have two different tables

### Location

```
User_ID       Locarion            start_date      end_date
----------      -------------    -------------   -------------
1               South             1-1-2018        1-5-2018
2               North             1-2-2018        1-11-2018
1               East              1-5-2018        1-9-2018
```

### User

```
User_ID       User_name       
----------      -------------   
1               Mary             
2               Sara
```

Using if statement to check if the current date is in between the star and end dates, return the location as current

i want this to be the result table

```
User_ID       User_name         current_location
----------      -------------   -------------
1               Mary             East
2               Sara             undeined
```

please help

Comment: So what exactly is your issue? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: SQL questions should always be tagged with the DBMS you are using by the way. The answer for, say, MySQL can be quite different from an answer for, say, SQL Server sometimes. So always tell us what DBMS you are asking for.

Comment: What is the data type of the start date and end date columns? because the answers below might not work with a varchar column.

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join with a join condition based on the dates:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, l.location as current_location
from users u
  left join location l 
         on l.user_id = u.user_id 
        and current_date between l.start_date and l.end_date;
```

This will return the location as `null` if there is no match. To display an alternative value use `coalesce(l.location, 'undefined')`

`BETWEEN` will include the start **and** the end date as a valid "location date".

If the end date should not be included, you need to use a different join condition:

```
select u.user_id, u.user_name, l.location as current_location
from users u
  left join location l 
         on l.user_id = u.user_id 
        and l.start_date >= current_date 
        and l.end_date < current_date;
```

You didn't specify your DBMS, but the above is standard ANSI SQL.

Online example: http://rextester.com/MMHVB20021

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select user_id,user_name,collasce(location,'undefined')
    from usertable u left join locationtable l on u.user_id=l.user_id
    and getdate>=startdate and getdate<=enddate
```

Comment: thank u @a_horse_with_no_name, modified my answer, i didn't notice it before

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fairly simple on, just use an Inner Join on User_ID and a case statement on the start and end dates, returning location or undefined.

Or if there are users without and entry for location, use a Left Join as specified by the other person, but I'd recommend NOT using BETWEEN unless you want the end date to be at the very start of the date, and not including the whole end date, i.e. til midnight.